# Avi video will not display properly with either the Videos program or with matlab's VideoReader, but it displays perfectly fine in vlc

Tags: video, vlc, matlab, gstreamer, avi

I am trying to load up some videos (avi files) into matlab to analyze them a bit; I recorded them using myCam 1.1 on Windows 7. I would like to analyze them on my linux computer; however, when I use either matlab's VideoReader program or the "Videos" program on ubuntu (20.04), each frame is unstable, every other frame jumps up and down. I do not get this behavior if I play the video in vlc on linux, or on any video player on windows...

Based on reading other posts on this website, it seems like it might be a codec issue; vlc comes prepackaged with codecs, and Videos (and I think VideoReader) do not.  However, I have updated the gstreamer1.0 codecs and I have installed the ubuntu-restricted-addons, and it did not solve my problem. Perhaps there is some codec which is not automatically installed in this manner, which I need to find?

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Jeffrey Boucher

Comment: Edit: I've found a workaround where I convert my videos to mp4 format with mpeg 2, using vlc. The videos look good when I put them in that format. However, it would be nice to be able to avoid this, or at least have a better understanding of what was going wrong...

Comment: Doing so, I've realized, cuts my framerate in half, but perhaps there is no avoiding this... 

Some additional information: my avi files use mjpeg video encoding, apparently.